# Gradle Build failed Failed to notify project evaluation listener

Tags: java, gradle

I'm tring to compile and I'm not able to get rid of the error.

I use Gradle 7.0;

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url = 'https://files.minecraftforge.net/maven' }
        maven { url = 'https://repo.spongepowered.org/maven' }
        maven {
            name = 'impactdevelopment-repo'
            url = 'https://impactdevelopment.github.io/maven/'
        }
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
        gradlePluginPortal()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath group: 'com.github.ImpactDevelopment', name: 'ForgeGradle', version: '3.0.115'
        classpath group: 'com.github.ImpactDevelopment', name: 'MixinGradle', version: '0.6.2'
        classpath group: 'gradle.plugin.com.github.jengelman.gradle.plugins', name: 'shadow', version: '7.0.0'
    }
}
```

Im using the following Plugins:

```
plugins {
    id 'de.undercouch.download' version '4.0.0'
    id 'com.github.johnrengelman.shadow' version '7.0.0'
    id 'java'
}
```

This ist the FAILURE.

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'addon-example'.
> Failed to notify project evaluation listener.
   > org.gradle.internal.nativeintegration.services.FileSystems.getDefault()Lorg/gradle/internal/nativeplatform/filesystem/FileSystem;
   > Could not create task ':createMcpToSrg'.
      > Could not create task ':extractSrg'.
         > java.lang.NullPointerException (no error message)
   > Could not create task ':createMcpToObf'.
      > Could not create task ':extractSrg'.
         > java.lang.NullPointerException (no error message)

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 8.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/7.0.1/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

BUILD FAILED in 2s
```

Stacktrace:

http://paste.cytooxien.de/buqugivuso.cs

Does anybody now how I can fix that?

Comment: You are using some Gradle plugin that you are not showing here. Please add the details.

Comment: I added the Plugins.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My soulution was to downgrade gradle to 4.10.3. I think the plugin I used only support gradle versions less than 5